# How to add column separator in Grid created by using grid.mvc and bootstrap in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created grid in MVC5 like

[image: image 1].

---

But I want a vertical line as a column separator like

[image: image 2]

---

I'm using grid.mvc (version: 3.0.0) of nugget package and default bootstrap for VS2013(MVC5).

---

Here is my Gridmvc.css

```
/***
*   Grid.Mvc stylesheet http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/
*   This file contains default styles for Grid.Mvc.
*/
/* Grid */
table.grid-table { margin: 0; }
    table.grid-table .grid-wrap { padding: 0; position: relative; }
    table.grid-table .grid-empty-text { color: #666; }

    /* Grid headers */
    table.grid-table .grid-header { position: relative; }
        table.grid-table .grid-header .sorted-asc .grid-sort-arrow:after { content: " \2193"; }
        table.grid-table .grid-header .sorted-desc .grid-sort-arrow:after { content: " \2191"; }
        table.grid-table .grid-header > .grid-header-title { border: #999999 1px solid;height: 21px;background-color: #f0f0f0;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden; }

    /* Grid body */
    /*table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected td { background: #4888C2 !important; color: white; }*/
    table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected td { margin-bottom: 1px; padding-top: 0px; border: #000000 1px solid; height: 21px; }
    /*table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a { color: white; }*/
    table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a { margin-bottom: 1px; color: #000000; padding-top: 1px; border: #c4ddff 1px solid; height: 21px; background-color: #a7cdf0; }



/* Grid filtering */
input.grid-filter-input { padding: 4px; font-size: 13px; }
table.grid-table .grid-filter { position: relative; margin-top: 2px; float: right; width: 10px; height: 12px; }
table.grid-table .grid-filter-btn { cursor: pointer; display: block; width: 10px; height: 12px; background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAMCAYAAABbayygAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAadEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjEwMPRyoQAAAJFJREFUKFNjkJSU/E8MZvj//78DMRhkoj+6bizYH2SiiIeHx2FjY+P/2DBIDqSGAQSOHTtmYWZm9hldEUgMJAdWBAJAHSzt7e056ApBYiA5qDIIAAoIhIaGroYpArFBYlBpVLB3715DmEIQGyqMCUDWwBRiWIkOYAqhXNwApMjX13c7lIsbgBQBrdWAcqGAgQEAdOGTrvsYKXIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') no-repeat; }
    table.grid-table .grid-filter-btn.filtered { background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAMCAYAAABbayygAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAadEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjEwMPRyoQAAAJNJREFUKFNjYGj//58o/P//fwdiMIOkpKQ/VhOQMFgNULWIh4fHYWNj4//YMEgOpIYBBI4dO2ZhZmb2GV0RSAwkB1YEAkAdLO3t7TnoCkFiIDmoMggACgiEhoauhikCsUFiUGlUsHfvXkOYQhAbKowJQNbAFGJYiQ5gCqFc3ACkyNfXdzuUixuAFAGt1YByoYCBAQAUDanUpFB4UQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') no-repeat; }
table.grid-table .grid-filter-buttons { padding: 0; }
table.grid-table .grid-filter-datepicker { font-size: 12px; }
    table.grid-table .grid-filter-datepicker table td { padding: 1px!important; }
    table.grid-table .grid-filter-datepicker .ui-datepicker { width: auto; }
table.grid-table .grid-dropdown-inner ul.menu-list li a.grid-filter-clear { white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 23px; background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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'); background-position: 3px center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
table.grid-table .grid-filter-choose.choose-selected { background-color: white!important; cursor: default; color: #999; }
table.grid-table .grid-popup-additional { padding: 3px 0 0 0; }

/* POP-UP */
.grid-dropdown { font-weight: normal; left: -102px; top: 16px!important; min-width: 180px; }
.grid-dropdown-arrow { background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAICAYAAADJEc7MAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABp0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuMTAw9HKhAAAAl0lEQVQoU42PMQuFMAyE6xN5gpOjjsIb/P9/o3O3zh27dY25kIPq8DBwmLT35WoQkUEVOmGec84CaW2q7+N+AdCD6M9SisQYTei1jsfyCeCu+vjFVGs1AN++94DRfUOfuNLoKUiyRC5y2F5I8NdaM4P/l0EswvBorQTnfxBhLMRih+2pklIy+eEtjQPu6MNZwIBNbwteMBd5X4ZGHcwL3QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat; height: 8px; left: 99px; position: absolute; top: -8px; width: 14px; }
.grid-dropdown-inner { padding: 5px 7px; }
.grid-dropdown ul.menu-list { list-style-type: none; margin: 3px 0 0 0; padding: 0; }
    .grid-dropdown ul.menu-list li a { text-decoration: none; background-position: 6px center; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: block; padding: 4px 5px; }
        .grid-dropdown ul.menu-list li a:hover { background-color: #EEE; text-decoration: none; }
```

---

Comment: Have you tried adding a right border on your cells?

Comment: @heymega can you guide me where to add right border in Gridmvc.css ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added these two lines under ***GridBody*** in `Gridmvc.css` :

```
table.grid-table tr td {border-right: solid 1px #666;} 
table.grid-table tr a {border-right: solid 1px #666;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a right border to your table you need to apply it to your table headings and table data tags

Add this to your CSS and place it after the gridmvc.css.

```
td, th {
    border-right: 4px solid black;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Gridmvc.css is used to style the grid controls. The actual look and feel is defined by bootstrap. If you want to add the styling to Gridmvc.css just place it at the end of the file. You may need to add !important to the end.

Comment: I got a solution to my problem. Add these two lines under GridBody :

table.grid-table tr td {border-right: solid 1px #666;}

table.grid-table tr a {border-right: solid 1px #666;}